# Prove that the ideal $\langle x^2+1\rangle$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Prove that the ideal $\langle x^2+1\rangle$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

$\textbf{My attempt:}$  Let $f(x)g(x) \in \langle x^2+1\rangle$, then $(x^2+1) \mid f(x)g(x)$.

I want to prove that wither $f(x) \in \langle x^2+1\rangle$ or $g(x) \in \langle x^2+1\rangle$, i.e., either $(x^2+1) \mid f(x)$ or $(x^2+1) \mid g(x)$.

We write the following: $$f(x) = (x^2+1)q(x) + (ax+b)\ \text{and}\ g(x) =(x^2+1)r(x)+ (cx+d)$$

If we reduce it in modulo $(x^2+1)$  we get $$f(x)\equiv ax+b \ \ \ \  (\bmod (x^2+1))\ \text{and}\ g(x)\equiv cx+d\ \ \ \  (\bmod (x^2+1))$$ If we multiply the above two relations, we get $$f(x)g(x) \equiv (ax+b)(cx+d) \ \ \ \ (\bmod (x^2+1))$$ Hence, \begin{align}(x^2+1) \mid f(x)g(x) \implies (x^2+1)\mid (ax+b)(cx+d)\end{align}

By the long division method, we see that if we divide $(ax+b)(cx+d)$ by $x^2+1$ then we get $(ad+bc)x +(bd-ac)$ as reminder. Hence, $\fbox{ad+bc =0}$ and $\fbox{bd-ac=0}$. If we multiply by $a$ (assuming $a\neq 0)$ to the both sides of $\fbox{bd=ac}$, we get  $$(ad)b = a^{2} c \implies -b^2c = a^2c \implies c(a^2+b^2) = 0$$ Since $a\neq 0$ then $a^2+c^2 \neq 0$ and this implies $\fbox{c=0}$. Putting $\fbox{c=0}$ in $\fbox{ad+bc =0}$, we get $\fbox{d=0}$. Hence, $cx+d \equiv 0$, i.e., $(x^2+1) \mid g(x)$. Therefore, $g(x) \in \langle x^2+1\rangle$. So, our proof is done.

Is it correct? Thanks.

Comment: Uhh, this proves that $\langle x^2 +1 \rangle$ IS prime.
A simpler proof is that $\mathbb Z[i]$ is a domain.

Comment: Have you not just proven that $\langle x^2+1\rangle$ *is* prime in $\mathbb Z[x]$? (One small note: "assuming $a\ne 0$..." - if $a=0$, then you similarly get $b=0$ i.e. $x^2+1\mid f(x)$.)

Comment: @StinkingBishop Sorry, the original question  asked  to prove that the ideal $\langle x^2+1\rangle$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Comment: what about irreduciblity? Moreover, we are working on integers.

Comment: The second part of your proof can be simplified by excursion to complex numbers. If $(ax+b)(cx+d)$ is divisible by $x^2+1$, then substituting $x=i$ you get that $(ai+b)(ci+d)=0$ i.e. one of $ai+b$ or $ci+d$ is $0$ etc.